# Auto Printing the created itext report in Java

Tags: java, printing

I have created the itext report when button pressed and coded to auto printing the created report.

some code of that;

```
DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
                    AttributeSet attributeSet = new HashAttributeSet();
                    attributeSet.add(new PrinterName("NPI8DA48A", null));
                    PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

                    DocPrintJob job= service.createPrintJob();
                    Doc pdfp = new SimpleDoc(salepdf, flavor, null);
                    PrintJobWatcher watcher = new PrintJobWatcher(job);
                    job.print(pdfp, null);
                    watcher.waitForDone();
```

but this shows and exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: data is not of declared type
at javax.print.SimpleDoc.<init>(SimpleDoc.java:103)
at com.bit.project.Newsale.saveprint_btnActionPerformed(Newsale.java:1128)
at com.bit.project.Newsale.access$1300(Newsale.java:57)
at com.bit.project.Newsale$16.actionPerformed(Newsale.java:683)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
```

line 1128 is `DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;`.

Comment: Don't know if it will make a difference, but there is a PDF `DocFlavor`, [`DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PDF`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.html#PDF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: data is not of declared type` seems to indicate that there is a mismatch between the data and the `DocFlavor`.

Since you're using `DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE`, I'm guessing either that it can't read your `salepdf` or it isn't a `InputStream`.

When I tested your code, I had to make sure that the data was a `InputStream`, reading from a PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

From [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/SimpleDoc.html#SimpleDoc(java.lang.Object,%20javax.print.DocFlavor,%20javax.print.attribute.DocAttributeSet)), the `SimpleDoc` constructor will throw a `IllegalArgumentException` if either of the first two arguments are null, or if the first does not correspond to the specified doc flavor. Therefore, I would make sure that `salepdf` is actually an `INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE`, and is actually getting initialized properly